# finding pattern from cURL output

Tags: python-2.7, awk, sed

I get the below data from a cURL output. I am only interested in data after `data-key` and `issue-link-summary`. Please help me with this. Here is a reference output

```
<div class="aui-group split-view"><div class="aui-item list-results-panel"><div class="list-panel"><div class="list-ordering"></div><div class="list-content"><ol class="issue-list"><li  data-id="95253" data-key="WXYZ-15288" title="b1-257-07.ch.abcde.com /grid/* 100%,"><a class="splitview-issue-link" data-issue-key="WXYZ-15288" href="/browse/WXYZ-15288"><img height="16" width="16" alt="Incident" title="Incident - " src="/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&amp;avatarId=11100&amp;avatarType=issuetype" />&nbsp;<span class="issue-link-key">WXYZ-15288</span><br/><span class="issue-link-summary">b1-257-07.ch.abcde.com /grid/* 100%,</span></a></li><li  data-id="95073" data-key="WXYZ-15238" title="restarting h4dn30.nm.abcde.com region server,"><a class="splitview-issue-link" data-issue-key="WXYZ-15238" href="/browse/WXYZ-15238"><img height="16" width="16" alt="Incident" title="Incident - " src="/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&amp;avatarId=11100&amp;avatarType=issuetype" />&nbsp;<span class="issue-link-key">WXYZ-15238</span><br/><span class="issue-link-summary">restarting h4dn30.nm.abcde.com region server,</span></a></li><li  data-id="95047" data-key="WXYZ-15230" title="Fwd: Alert: abcd-fgh-db1.nm.abcde.com/Mysql Uptime,"><a class="splitview-issue-link" data-issue-key="WXYZ-15230" href="/browse/WXYZ-15230"><img height="16" width="16" alt="Incident" title="Incident - " src="/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&amp;avatarId=11100&amp;avatarType=issuetype" />&nbsp;<span class="issue-link-key">WXYZ-15230</span><br/><span class="issue-link-summary">Fwd: Alert: abcd-fgh-db1.nm.abcde.com/Mysql Uptime,</span></a></li><li  data-id="94928" data-key="WXYZ-15194" title="Re: [CRITICAL ALERT! Reached Rule: XX_eml_slayer_label_production"><a class="splitview-issue-link" data-issue-key="WXYZ-15194" href="/browse/WXYZ-15194"><img height="16" width="16" alt="Incident" title="Incident - " src="/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&amp;avatarId=11100&amp;avatarType=issuetype" />&nbsp;<span class="issue-link-key">WXYZ-15194</span><br/><span class="issue-link-summary">Re: [CRITICAL] ALERT! Reached Rule: XX_eml_slayer_label_production</span></a></li><li  data-id="94925" data-key="WXYZ-15193" title="Re: [CRITICAL] ALERT! Breached Rule: Reached Rule: XX_eml_slayer_label_production"><a class="splitview-issue-link" data-issue-key="WXYZ-15193" href="/browse/WXYZ-15193"><img height="16" width="16" alt="Incident" title="Incident - " src="/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&amp;avatarId=11100&amp;avatarType=issuetype" />&nbsp;<span class="issue-link-key">WXYZ-15193</span><br/><span class="issue-link-summary">Re: [CRITICAL] ALERT! Reached Rule: XX_eml_slayer_label_production</span></a></li></ol></div></div><div class="end-of-stable-message-container"></div><div class="aui-group pagination-view count-pagination"><div class="refresh-container aui-item"><a href="#" class="refresh-table" title="Refresh results">Refresh results</a></div><div class="pagination-container aui-item"><div class="pagination" data-displayable-total="5"></div></div></div></div><div class="aui-item detail-panel navigator-issue-only"><div></div></div></div>
```

Please note that the entire output appears in a single line. The number of fields can vary.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @Avinash Raj:
The expected output should display something like:

`WXYZ-15288            b1-257-07.ch.abcde.com /grid/* 100%,`

Please note that the trailing comma might not always be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
awk -vRS="=" '/data-key/ {f=NR} f && NR==f+1 {print "data-key="$1}'
data-key="WXYZ-15288"
data-key="WXYZ-15238"
data-key="WXYZ-15230"
data-key="WXYZ-15194"
data-key="WXYZ-15193"
```

---

Updated:

```
awk -vRS="[<>]" -F\" '/data-key.*title/ {print $4,$6}' file
WXYZ-15288 b1-257-07.ch.abcde.com /grid/* 100%,
WXYZ-15238 restarting h4dn30.nm.abcde.com region server,
WXYZ-15230 Fwd: Alert: abcd-fgh-db1.nm.abcde.com/Mysql Uptime,
WXYZ-15194 Re: [CRITICAL ALERT! Reached Rule: XX_eml_slayer_label_production
WXYZ-15193 Re: [CRITICAL] ALERT! Breached Rule: Reached Rule: XX_eml_slayer_label_production
```

Comment: Thanks but that wouldnt help me. I was able to get that output by running 
`awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if($i~/^data-key/) {print $i}}} ` against the file that holds the data.. I will require both ID number and the data within `issue-link-summary` as well.

Comment: @rickydj Then post example output of how you like the result to be from your input.

Comment: The expected output should display something like:

`WXYZ-15288            b1-257-07.ch.abcde.com /grid/* 100%,`

Please note that the trailing comma might not always be there.

Comment: @rickydj Still not clear.  There are several `data-key` and several `issue-link-summary`, and still not clear what rules are to select one but not other.

Comment: Thanks Jotne. It works.

note: awk -v is not a reconginsed switch on mac. It works on my servers though. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @rickydj Then try with space `awk -v RS="[<>]" -F\" '/data-key.*title/ {print $4,$6}' file` or variable at end `awk -F\" '/data-key.*title/ {print $4,$6}' RS="[<>]" file`

Comment: I installed gawk on my mac and replace awk with gawk. It works fine now. Thanks for the tip. 

I am really curious to figure what `awk -v RS="[<>]"` means. I tried running it after you wrote the code and I know how it behaves but I guess I didnt understand the logic. 

Also, after `'/data-key.*title/`. Why is there a `*title`? I get the same ouput without that as well. It would be great if you could explain the logic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @rickydj Normally a new line `\n` set the record, so one line at a time.  By using `-v RS="[<>]"` you set the Record Selector to either `<` or `>`.